# CocoaPods - Unable to find a specification for

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My Podfile looks like this:

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
--source= 'git@bitbucket.org:appstrakt/apps-tool-libraries-appletech-specs-private.git'
--source= 'git@bitbucket.org:appstrakt/apps-tool-libraries-appletech-specs-test.git'

target 'Test' do
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

# Fabric
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

# Appstrakt Pods
pod 'NovemberFiveApplication-iOS', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Dye', '~> 2.0'
pod 'APGoogleAnalytics', '~> 2.0'
pod 'APCrashlyticsAnalytics', '~> 2.0'
pod 'APLoggerServiceBasic', '~> 2.0'

# Dexter
pod 'Dexter', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'DEXHTTPMonitorModule', '~> 0.0.1'

# 3rd Party Pods
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Lockbox', '~> 1.4'
pod 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'

pod 'Reveal-SDK'

end

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
```

When I run 'pod install', I got an error:

> Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to find a specification for
>   `NovemberFiveApplication-iOS (~> 2.0)`
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
>   `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.  * mistyped the
>   name or version.  * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec
>   to your Podfile.

Comment: It doesn't know "NovemberFiveApplication-iOS". Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: Try execute command  ```pod repo update```.
When the Pod Library to be new versions can sometimes cause errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NovemberFiveApplication-iOS` is not a public CocoaPod. To install it you will need to add the repo: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

November Five seem to be a business, with no open source repo. To use their SDK you will need to get the repo from them.